# SyntaxError: invalid syntax python pandas using

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error, readfile

I'm trying to read a file and I'm getting this error. The file is in the same folder as the project.

> C:\Users\Администратор\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> C:\Users\Администратор\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\test\main\test.csv
> File
> "C:\Users\Администратор\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\test\main\test.csv",
> line 2
> 1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

```
import pandas as pd

df11 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df11[:5])
```

Comment: You just appear the be hitting "Run" on the wrong file there in PyCharm. Make sure you're running the *Python file*, not the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You are running `python.exe` with argument `test.csv`, trying to run csv as a python script, which is obviously not a python script, thus the error.

try running `python.exe main.py` instead

Comment: And could you suggest how to do it? I don't understand.

Tell me, please,
Is it possible to open a document without correcting errors, but ignoring them? open as is?

Comment: Its seems like an IDE configuration problem, edit your run configuration so it runs your python code, not your csv